# Перестала работать библиотека pyowm (https://openweathermap.org)

Tags: python, pyowm

Ранее код на Питоне работал отлично, но в последние дни такая ошибка. Проблема на их стороне или на моей или всю Россию отключили от сервиса?

```
raise ConnectTimeout(e, request=request)
```

requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.openweathermap.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /data/2.5/weather?APPID=c683a8a2d1f5f1d0d4fea73acfe0d0fc&lang=en&q=Krasnodar (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x00000166235CA370>, 'Connection to api.openweathermap.org timed out. (connect timeout=5)'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Answer (score 0):

Та же история, пробовал на 3.0 - так же не отвечает, любые примеры приведенные в документации не работают...

Попробовал с vpn запрос сделать - всё ок. Похоже только в России перестал работать

Comment: не совсем так, если вводить в браузер например http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?APPID=c683a8a2d1f5f1d0d4fea73acfe0d0fc&lang=en&q=Krasnodar то json от api приходит, больше похоже что сломалось что-то в библиотеках, потому что бот в тг месяц назад написанный и лежащий на русском сервере продолжает работать

Comment: Вот что ответили с OWM:
info@openweathermap.org  
пн, 23 мая, 19:45 (3 дня назад)
кому: мне

Hello, thank you for contacting us.

There was some news that came out yesterday: https://habr.com/ru/news/t/667096/.  That some services might not work. I would recommend using a VPN.

If you have any other questions, please don’t hesitate and contact us.

Kind regards,
Artūras Rosliakas
Technical Support Specialist

Comment: я отписался вчера ниже, если ssl проверку отключить все работает как раньше, по крайней мере на 2.5, 3.0 пока не пробовал.

Comment: да, на 2.5 убрал из https запросов "s" - всё заработало. спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Была такая же проблема решил таким образом:

```
from pyowm.utils.config import get_default_config
config_dict = get_default_config()
config_dict['connection']['use_ssl'] = False
config_dict['connection']["verify_ssl_certs"] = False
owm = OWM(TOKEN, config_dict)
```